# JPA/JDO entity to XML XSD generator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, xsd, jdo, datanucleus

I am using JDO or JPA on GAE plugin in Eclipse.
I am using smartgwt datasource, accepting an xsd.

I would like to be educated how to generate an XSD from my jdo/jpa entity, vice versa.

Is there a tool to do it?

While datanucleas does all its magic enhancing in the Eclipse background, would I be able to somehow operate in a mode that would generate XSDs for me?
Can Hibernate operate in an offline mode, to solely help me generate XSDs which I could use in GWT without deploying hibernate with my web-app? Can Hibernate even be capable of generating XSDs from entities, vice versa?

Currently, I am about to write a utility to generate an xsd, given an entity class - but I am hoping I don't have to reinvent the wheel if it already exists.

I am hoping people here could educate me on any available tools to ease my XSD generation.

*But btw, I am very wary of anything that uses Maven, because most people (like Spring) who write the Maven scripts and pom don't have the expertise to write it in a way that would spew out messages and verbosity appropriately to make it easy for me to locate model errors.*

Comment: I very much prefer something that is annotation driven.

Comment: Presume you mean an XML file for ORM, because an "XSD" is the schema definition of that XML file and you do not need to generate that since its provided with any implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking into Hyperjaxb3 project.